# Jmeter Keycloak Authorization_code

Tags: jmeter, keycloak, load-testing, blazemeter

Im currently trying to load test a website with keycloak authorization.
The problem is that i cant find the authorization code anywhere in the previous https requests, so i cant use the regular expression extractor to grab it and turn it to a dynamic variable. So how do i configure it to be dynamic?
[the auhorization code as it was recorded with blazemeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMWSr.png)

i already turned to session_code, tab_id and executive into dynamic variables, but it still returns "{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Code not valid"}"

Answer (score 0):

As per [Authorization Code Flow](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#authorization-code-flow):

> 1. Browser visits application. The application notices the user is not logged in, so it redirects the browser to Keycloak to be authenticated. The application passes along a callback URL (a redirect URL) as a query parameter in this browser redirect that Keycloak will use when it finishes authentication.
> 2. Keycloak authenticates the user and creates a one-time, very short lived, temporary code. Keycloak redirects back to the application using the callback URL provided earlier and additionally adds the temporary code as a query parameter in the callback URL.
> 3. The application extracts the temporary code and makes a background out of band REST invocation to Keycloak to exchange the code for an identity, access and refresh token. Once this temporary code has been used once to obtain the tokens, it can never be used again. This prevents potential replay attacks.

My expectation is that you don't see the code anywhere because the code has been passed from keycloak to the application via the [redirect URL](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/).

So instead of asking keycloak to send the redirect back to application with the temporary code you need to ask it to send the request **to JMeter** and catch it via i.e. [HTTP Mirror Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Mirror_Server), once the request reaches JMeter you should be able to get the temporary code using [Regular Expression Extractor or Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-boundary-extractor-vs-the-regular-expression-extractor-in-jmeter/) from the [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) header.